# How to normalize an already started database with primary key ID values, as small as possible?

Tags: mysql, database, normalization

As time passes and the database has a lot of INSERTs, the auto increment primary key IDs of the tables can get quite big, especially if the INSERTs are automated by some automated process. I know that a MySQL INT field (for example) has this range: signed from -2147483648 to 2147483647, or unsigned from 0 to 4294967295. It is difficult to reach those limit values ​​(but not impossible). Is there a command or process that normalizes the IDs to smallest possible values? If the value of an auto increment ID of a table arrived at 967295, but then for some reason the last 967200 INSERTs are deleted, how do I normalize the table so that the next auto increment is 96, initially respecting all secondary keys and maintaining the intact structure?

Comment: Database normalization has absolutely nothing to do with actual key values.

Comment: No, there's nothing that will automatically renumber everything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make MySQL auto-increment id (re) start from 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409718/make-mysql-auto-increment-id-re-start-from-1)

Comment: If all the foreign keys have `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, you can write your own procedure to renumber the master table, and they'll propagate to all the references.

Comment: I worked at a place that hit the limit on primary keys. It wasn't pretty.

Comment: @Schwern We hit the limit in one of our tables, then we changed it from INT to UNSIGNED to double the size.

Comment: @Schwern, Yeah, I consulted for a site that hit the max signed INT value in their `Users` table, which naturally had about 30 other tables referencing it. We had to upgrade all the dependent tables to BIGINT first, then upgrade the `Users` table, because it would have been a problem to insert new rows in `Users` that couldn't be referenced by the other tables. While all these alterations were running, they couldn't process new user signups.

Comment: @Barmar, I've always thought that doubling the range by using UNSIGNED is only a temporary solution. If an app reaches 2^31, it's likely to reach 2^32 in even less time.

Comment: @BillKarwin Yes, but it's also a quick, easy fix, as it doesn't require rebuilding the table, which will be very slow for a large table.

Comment: @Barmar, Changing from INT to INT UNSIGNED does require rebuilding the table. Try: `alter table mytable modify column id int unsigned, algorithm=inplace, lock=none;` You get an error that it can't be done inplace.

Comment: @BillKarwin I thought it could be done in place because it doesn't change the size or representation of the values, just how they're interpreted (similar to adding a value to ENUM). It's been several years, I guess I didn't remember how long it took.

Comment: @Barmar, It doesn't change the number of bytes or number of distinct values, but it changes the ordering of values.

Comment: @BillKarwin Oh, because it's the primary key.

Comment: @Barmar, The same error is returned if you try to modify a non-key column from INT to INT UNSIGNED. Even if it's not indexed. The exception is only for changing the length of varchar/varbinary, but other data type changes require a table copy. Cf. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77097

Comment: @RobertoRocco I generally don't recommend renumbering the primary key values. It can cause confusion if you had shared those id values outside the database. 

For example,  if you send an email with a link, then six months later you renumber all the entities, then the recipient finally opens their email and clicks on that link, they'll view the wrong record (or no record at all).

I recommend you just use BIGINT primary keys for any tables that might grow larger than 2^31.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a command or process that normalizes the IDs to smallest possible values? If the value of an auto increment ID of a table arrived at 967295, but then for some reason the last 967200 INSERTs are deleted, it is possible to normalize the table so that the next auto increment is 96, initially respecting all secondary keys and maintaining the intact structure?

There is no command because primary keys aren't supposed to change.

You could write a program to periodically scan the table for large gaps and then change the primary keys to use the next available one. And you'd also have to change everywhere it is used as a foreign key.

This will not work with an autoincremented primary key. Autoincrement is a simple counter, it will not jump gaps for you. You'd have to normalize every entry in the table every time, then reset the autoincrement to `max(id)`. Rewriting most of the rows in the table will be slow and will cause locks. Alternatively, you'd write an insert trigger to find the next available key; slow and complicated.

This assumes there is nothing outside the database referring to the primary key. For example, `http://example.com/thing/123` where `123` is an ID in the `things` table.

---

There are two better solutions.

1. Use a UUID primary key.
2. Use a bigint primary key.

[UUID primary keys solve and create problems](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-uuid/). They're awkward in MySQL. And they require 16 bytes, 12 more than an int.

Bigints work just like ints. They only take 4 more bytes. They're the native integer type on any modern hardware. They're a simple upgrade that only has to be done once: alter the type of the primary key and its foreign keys. You might run out of 2 billion or even 4 billion primary keys. You're not going to run out of 9,223,372,036,854,775,808.

Comment: Assuming you have a typical incrementation, that's correct. But if you increment the primary key by 4 billion each time one is inserted, you could run out of BIGINT just as fast as you would run out of INT while incrementing by 1. This may seem like a silly thing to call out, but don't underestimate the talent of developers to sabotage any system.

Comment: @BillKarwin You can't put a price on hiring talent like that.